# Finding azure Availability sets using Azure in classic mode

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-vm-role, azure-availability-set

I am trying to find the availability sets in a Azure Cloud Service using powershell. The Cloud Service was created using classic model.

I am not sure if this is the right answer:

```
get-AzureService -ServiceName "myService"
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. Get-AzureService returns with the information about the cloud services for the current subscription.

The Syntax is:

```
Get-AzureService -ServiceName "nameOfService"
```